# How do i add layout to the homepage of my site

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, home, home-page

How do I add a layout to the homepage of my site? The homepage content is NOT a full screen and id like to add a full-width banner with a clickable button on it just like what we have here on
[this site](http://us.asos.com/)

However, I tried using the static block for this but it didn't work. I am new to Magento and would really appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: which version you are using and are you using any custom theme or RWD theme?

Comment: I am using version 1.9 and a custom theme. On the custom theme, they used a cms block. On the content tab, they used some HTML div tags which is by default, in a boxed layout, and on the design tab, they used an XML to call on the slider which is in fullwidth.

Comment: have a look to this first for https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95643/how-can-i-make-the-rwd-theme-full-width?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I am not looking to make the website fullwidth, just to remove the slider and replace with a banner like the website I referenced above.

Comment: if you know the xml which is calling the slider than you can remove from that section and to call banner you can use static block and call in the fashion

Comment: This is the XML calling the slider but I do not know what to replace.     <reference name="home.before.content">
<block type="nwdrevslider/revslider" name="revslider"><action method="setAlias"><alias>fashion</alias></action></block>
</reference>

Comment: first you have to open/find the layout which is active than you can follow this https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-add-a-new-static-block-to-the-headerfooter-section.html

Comment: TO make it clickable you have to use css and js ( for this you can create a template and than call it )

Comment: i posted an answer is that you want ?

Comment: I understand now but one problem is, I do not want to add to the header, rather on the body

Comment: you want to call static block in body right >

Comment: Thank you for accepting as answer but is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I add a layout to the homepage of my site?

**Suggestion:** There is defaults layout which Magento provides which can be easily changed for a page from the backend.

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/

1. To insert a cms Block directly:

`{{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_block_id"}}`

2. You can use widgets for the same

   1. In the Editor toolbar, click on insert Widget
   2. Choose Static Block
   3. Choose the Block you want to insert

In the widget, we can easily call our blocks in the different reference which are created:

[image: inrsaurabh]

Answer (score 0):

in order to create custom layout for Magento 1.x cms pages you have to create a custom module:

Module directory / file(s) structure :

> app/etc/modules/Home_PageFullwidth.xml
>
> app/code/local/Home/PageFullwidth/etc/config.xml
>
> app/design/frontend/{Theme-Vendor/{Theme-name}/page/home-page.phtml

**app/etc/modules/Home_PageFullwidth.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config>
<modules>
  <Home_PageFullwidth>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
    <depends>
        <Mage_Page />
    </depends>
</Home_PageFullwidth>
</modules>
```

**app/code/local/Home/PageFullwidth/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
         <modules>
            <Home_PageFullwidth>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Home_PageFullwidth>
         </modules>
               <global>
                   <page>
                     <layouts>
                        <PageFullwidth translate="label">
                               <label>1Column-fullWidth</label>
                                 <template>page/home-page.phtml</template>
                               <layout_handle>homepage_fullwidth</layout_handle>
                        </PageFullwidth>
                     </layouts>
                   </page>
              </global>
     </config>
```

And finally your template file **page/home-page.phtml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
    <head>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
    </head>
    <body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
        <div class="page">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_notice') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer') ?>
            <div class="main-container col1-layout">
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="col-main">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```